# How to create a folder within the MySQL datadir without MySQL treating it as a database?

Tags: mysql

For example, I needed to create a directory called 'backup' within the `datadir` (temporarily) to store a backup file, but I noticed that MySQL interprets this directory as a database within MySQL. Is this safe? Is it possible to create a directory within the `datadir` without MySQL thinking it's a database?"

Comment: Why do you need to do it within datadir?

Comment: The only mount point where we have free space enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is not possible to create a folder in datadir without it being treated as a schema.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/data-directory.html says:

> Each subdirectory of the data directory is a database directory and corresponds to a database managed by the server.

If you need to use the disk volume for other files besides MySQL data, you should relocate your datadir path to one level down below the mount point. Then make a sister folder so you can store other files.

Or add another large volume to your server on a different mount point.

Comment: And what about --ignore-db-dir parameter ?

Comment: @lear1 Cf. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_ignore-db-dir _" This option is deprecated in MySQL 5.7. With the introduction of the data dictionary in MySQL 8.0, it became superfluous and was removed in that version. "_